# How do I get the font file or PDFont of each word in a PDF file?

Tags: java, pdfbox

Is there a way to get the font of each word of a PDF file using PDFBox? I have tried this but it just lists all the fonts used on that page.

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("xxofd.pdf"));

    PDPageTree pages = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
    for (PDPage page : pages) {
        PDResources res = page.getResources();

        for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames()) {
            PDFont font = null;
            try {
                font = res.getFont(fontName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

There are many different characters in the pdf file, and maybe different characters are different fonts. I want to extract a subset of these fonts. This subset only contains the fonts of the words that have appeared in the pdf file. This will make the font file smaller.So I want get the font file or PDFont structure of each word of a PDF file. Is there any way? Thanks.

Comment: In general you cannot set the `word => font` injection since a word can consist of characters with different font.

Comment: Yes, I want to see if there are other ways to extract font subsets

Comment: Most PDF files use font subsets.

Comment: Yes, I just got the font subset file from pdf, I can open it with FontForge . But I have a question. Why can't I directly click on this font subset file with the mouse, there will be an invalid font error? But the font subset file I got using sfnttool.jar can be opened directly by clicking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the PDF file:

[image]

then

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("/home/josejuan/tmp/fonts.pdf"));

PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper() {
    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
        System.out.println("Text `" + text.getUnicode() + "` with font `" + text.getFont().getName() + "`");
    }
};

// force parse
pdfStripper.getText(pdfDocument);
```

produce the expected output

```
Text `E` with font `BAAAAA+LiberationSerif`
Text `x` with font `BAAAAA+LiberationSerif`
Text `a` with font `CAAAAA+CantarellRegular`
Text `m` with font `CAAAAA+CantarellRegular`
Text `p` with font `BAAAAA+LiberationSerif`
....
```

(you can group by of course)

From that code you can describe every character of text, for example, if you need the font file:

```
text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontFile()
```

but depending on what exactly you are looking for it will be better to use `PDFont`, `PDFontDescriptor`, `PDStream`, ...

Comment: thanks，I can get the fontName of each character, but I want to get a valid font file, a font subset file containing the above characters

Comment: @Serendipity I have updated the answer but in `text.getFont()` you have all the information related to the specific text.

Comment: The method I used is similar to yours, but the font file obtained is not a valid font file.

Comment: @Serendipity I can convert the PDFont to other font file format by your question is _"How do I get the font file or PDFont of each word in a PDF file?"_ and my answer solve it (your solution does not track every character and the getFont return null). Please, accept my answer.

Comment: Well, the point of my question is wrong, I should ask how to convert PDFont into a valid font file,and thanks.

Comment: *"I should ask how to convert PDFont into a valid font file"* - depending on the source pdf that is the non-trivial part...

Comment: In fact, it is the one he has already solved, but moreover, it is not part of the question. (By the way, thank you for accepting the answer to your question).